# Finding text in html page without use of x path

Tags: selenium

How do i find this text in the following code without using x path ?
I am using selenium web driver
Following is the code :

```
<div id="second" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    <div>
          Please Enter Below Given Address In The TextBox
          <br>
          <br>
    <div>
          Company Name:
          <br>
          Location:
          <br>
          City:
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea cols="5" style="width:300px" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which text exactly? Show how you tried to solve the issue. Do you want to locate node by its text or you want your code to return text?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is

`driver.getPageSource().contains(text))`

Regards